# Is it possible to consume Parent property inside its own tag body without using @ref?

Tags: blazor

I am wondering if it is possible to read a component's property directly inside its own tag body without using `@ref`.

What I would like to do is replicate the same functionality of `@context`

As an example, I have a component called PermissionBox which take two parameters:

- PermissionId: is an Id used to read permissions
- Content: child component encapsulated inside PermissionBox body

and a public property:

- Permission: this property will be initialized during the `OnInitialized` event.

The behavior I would like to implement:

- by PermissionBox

  - if `Permission.IsVisible` then PermissionBox doesn't render the child element
- by Consumer

  - the consumer can directly read Permission from PermissionBox

Is it possible?

#### PermissionBox component

```cs
@if (Permission.IsVisible)
{
    @Content
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public string PermissionId { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment Content { get; set; }
    private Permission _Permission = null;
    public Permission Permission => _Permission;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        //some logic about PermissionId ...
        _Permission = new Permission
        {
            IsVisible = true,
            IsEditable = false
        };
    }
}
```

#### How I would like to use it

```cs
@page "/"

<PermissionBox PermissionId="">
    <MyComponent Enabled="@context.Permission.IsEnabled"></MyComponent>
</PermissionBox>

<p>Index page</p>

@code {

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you use a `generic` RenderFragment

```csharp
[Parameter] public RenderFragment<Permission> Content { get; set; }
```

And then pass your permission object to the RenderFragment

```csharp
@if (Permission.IsVisible)
{
    @Content(Permission)
}
```

In this case, `context` will actually be your Permission object

```html
<PermissionBox PermissionId="">
    <MyComponent Enabled="@context.IsEnabled"></MyComponent>
</PermissionBox>
```

Or you can "rename" context to permission if you want

```html
<PermissionBox PermissionId="" Context="permission">
    <MyComponent Enabled="@permission.IsEnabled"></MyComponent>
</PermissionBox>
```